# How can I manage a Unity project with GitLab? Following other guides has not worked

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, gitlab

I am at university doing a group project using Unity and we are trying to use GitLab for version control, but have had problems with gitignore and opening the project from the cloned repository. I feel I have read so many guides which have always resulted in the same problem. We are trying to do this for an existing project which we have been working on for a week (we only discovered our git problems recently).

The steps I have tried:

1. Created new git repo
2. Copied a working version of our Unity project across with all files and folders.
3. Opened the unity project and edited settings to show meta files and force text.
4. Added a git ignore file [from here](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Unity.gitignore).
5. Initialised git LFS and added .gitattributes.
6. Added, committed and pushed everything to origin master (library folder was not pushed, as one would expect).

Now to test that this would work for my team mates, I deleted my local repository folder and re-cloned the repository. However, the problem is that when I open the project in unity, it opens a blank scene with the message :

> rebuilding library because the asset database could not be found

I can browse through the assets folder and everything is in there, but Unity doesn't seem to be able to rebuild the project without the Library folder which is meant to be excluded from git.

I even tried to create a whole new unity project from scratch, just adding a simple cube to the scene, but when I went to the open the project it did the same thing.

I am at my wits end and having a client meeting in 2 days without a working git repository is a nightmare. I would hugely appreciate some help with this, I am at a dead end and I don't know what I am doing wrong, thanks.

I am using unity version 2017.4.10f1

Comment: You said that you're showing the meta files, but are they getting added to the repository? Be sure they are. Also, is there a particular reason for the version of Unity?

Comment: Looking through the assets, every file has a meta file in the git repo, so yes they appear to be added. The reason for the version is that I use a university laptop, and they cannot update software regularly to all students, so we all use this version. They are updated yearly I think.

Comment: This `rebuilding library because the asset database could not be found` is completely normal ;) nothing to worry about. Unity is just informing you that it is rebuilding it. The library folder is ignored in gitignore since Unity rebuilds it anyway. The only folders you really need are `Assets` and `ProjectSettings` all the rest can be ignored in most cases since Unity rebuilds everything when opening the project/opening visual studio